Ошибка при использование react-native-yamap с Expo
В документации сказано для использование нативного модуля в Expo надо сделать expo prebuild.Сделал prebuild появилась папка android.Но всё равно ошибки:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes````

